# How to reflect event that happened on the server, in the browser

Tags: node.js

I am a beginner with NodeJS. Now I am wondering how to signify/visualize an event that happened in the server. 
For example the event might happen once in every 20sec, and I want to give a signal in the browser that the have happened.

I was thinking about the approach to request/poll  the  server every 10mSec, but it doesn't seem to be very efficient.

Any better ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two way to propagate an event that happen into the server to the front.

- Front polling. Every X sec the front is gonna ask the server about news.

  **Front** : "did something happen?"

  **Back**  : "yes ..."
- Websocket communication. The front open a websocket connection to the server and then wait for news. As soon as something happen on the back, the server send a message to the front. No polling, no useless messages.

A famous websocket is [socket.io](https://socket.io/). What's used to create chats for example.

---

Schema representation of the difference of treatment :

[image]